# Are messages encrypted when consuming from Event Hub to my application? Is it SSL Secured?

Tags: azure, ssl, encryption, azure-eventhub

I am consuming messages from the Azure Event Hub to my application and I am successfully receiving the messages. I want to know whether the messages sent from the Event Hub is encrypted. I searched in learn.microsoft.com but could not find much information. It would be a great help if anyone can help me out to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

As you can find in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-consumers):

> Any entity that reads event data from an event hub is an event consumer. All Event Hubs consumers connect via the AMQP 1.0 session and events are delivered through the session as they become available...

Now, there is more documentation around the use of AMQP regarding to the Service Bus and Event Hub, it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide):

> It is the primary protocol of Azure Service Bus Messaging and Azure Event Hubs. Both services also support HTTPS.

and, more important in this context:

> Azure Service Bus ( *note: also Event Hub* ) requires the use of TLS at all times. It supports connections over TCP port 5671, whereby the TCP connection is first overlaid with TLS before entering the AMQP protocol handshake, and also supports connections over TCP port 5672 whereby the server immediately offers a mandatory upgrade of connection to TLS using the AMQP-prescribed model. The AMQP WebSockets binding creates a tunnel over TCP port 443 that is then equivalent to AMQP 5671 connections.

In addition, Event Hub data is encrypted at rest, see [the docs])(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest)

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response. Now I get a clear picture :)

Comment: So there is no message level encryption( The data itself ). The security is only for the Transport layer. Correct?

Comment: Correct! You'll have to encrypt them yourself if needed. You can upvote the feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216926-service-bus/suggestions/17420701-event-hub-encryption)

Comment: Looks like this feature is available now. Event Hubs both encrypt the data at rest. You can refer this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest)